# Rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've basicall got a rails app that serves XML happily but I now need to add a HTML admin area.  Whats the quickest way that I can do this?

My database and models are all happy and all I need now is run some magic script to turn it all into a website - is there anything that will do this?

If not - why not!?

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 1):

If you used scaffolding, just visit your routes without the .xml postfix. What is generated tends to be rather basic, with the intent of providing boilerplate that you come in and customize later. If you want something a bit more full featured, check out [ActiveScaffold](http://activescaffold.com/), or [Hobo](http://hobocentral.net/)